# QLIK SENSE distinct count with a sum

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I need to output the balance amount only if there is only one currency in the sample.
I found a way to output this condition separately for a particular currency:

`NUM(Sum({$<[currency]={'810'}>} [currency_balance]), '# ##0,00')`

Now I need to make sum output only when filtering is for one currency.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been solved.

It turned out to be simple:

`if(Count(distinct([currency]) = 1, Num(Sum([currency_balance]), '# ##0, 00')`